# python change value in nested dictionary if condition is met

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

I know similar questions have already been asked before, but I really having problems implementing them for my special case:

Let's say I have a dictionary with varying depths, for example:

```
dicti = {'files':
    {'a':{'offset':100, 'start': 0}, 
     'b':{
         'c':{'offset':50, 'start':0}
         'd':{'offset':70, 'start':0}  
         }
     'e':{
         'f':{'offset':80, 'start':0}
         'g':{'offset':30, 'start':0}  
         'h':{'offset':20, 'start':0}   
         } 
    }
        }
   etc... (with a lot more different levels and entries)
```

so now I want a copy of that dictionary with basically the same structure and keys, but if `'offset'` (at any level) is greater than let's say `50` `'offset'` should be changed to `0`

I guess some kind of iterative function would be the best, but I cannot get my head around that...

Comment: How does your data look like before being read into dictionary? May be you have better solution with python `pandas` module.

Comment: Yeah I don't like my data either, but it's loaded from a `json` file, so nothing I can do about that

Comment: There is a function to read in `json` in `pandas` http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html you get more structured data to operate with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use the standard machinery for the copy and then modify the copied dictionary (solution #1 in my example), or you might do copying and modification in the same function (solution #2).

In either case, you're looking for a recursive function.

```
import copy
from pprint import pprint
dicti = {'files':
    {'a':{'offset':100, 'start': 0},
     'b':{
         'c':{'offset':50, 'start':0},
         'd':{'offset':70, 'start':0},
         },
     'e':{
         'f':{'offset':80, 'start':0},
         'g':{'offset':30, 'start':0},
         'h':{'offset':20, 'start':0},
         }
    }
}

# Solution 1, two passes
def modify(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if d.get('offset', 0) > 50:
            d['offset'] = 0
        for k,v in d.items():
            modify(v)
dictj = copy.deepcopy(dicti)
modify(dictj)
pprint(dictj)

# Solution 2, copy and modify in one pass
def copy_and_modify(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        d2 = {k:copy_and_modify(v) for k,v in d.items()}
        if d2.get('offset') > 50:
            d2['offset'] = 0
        return d2
    return d
dictj = copy_and_modify(dicti)
pprint(dictj)
```

Comment: Thanks I really like your second solution, works like a charm!

Comment: Note that your sample did not include any `list` or `tuple` or otherwise iterable objects. If your real data does, you may need to update my solution.

Answer (score 2):

A recursive solution is going to be more intuitive.  You want something like the following pseudocode:

```
def copy(dict):
    new_dict = {}
    for key, value in dict:
        if value is a dictionary:
            new_dict[key] = copy(value)
        else if key == 'offset' and value > 50:
            new_dict[key] = 0
        else:
            new_dict[key] = value
    return new_dict
```

Comment: Is this slower than iterative functions when dealing with huge dictionaries?

Comment: `for key, value in dict:` is not going to work with an dictionary. Did you try it with an example dictionary?

Comment: @ccf That's why I said it's pseudocode.  Because I don't have an interpreter or a compiler that can run pseudocode (let me know if you know of one), I did not test it on an example dictionary

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'files':
    {'a':{'offset':100, 'start': 0},
     'b':{
         'c':{'offset':50, 'start':0},
         'd':{'offset':70, 'start':0}
         },
     'e':{
         'f':{'offset':80, 'start':0},
         'g':{'offset':30, 'start':0},
         'h':{'offset':20, 'start':0}
         }
    }
        }

def transform(item):
    new_item = item.copy()  # consider usage of deepcopy if needed
    if new_item['offset'] == 80:
        new_item['offset'] = 'CHANGED'
    return new_item

def visit(item):
    if item.get('offset'):
        return transform(item)
    else:
        return {k: visit(v) for k, v in item.items()}

result = visit(d)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{
    'files': {
        'b': {
            'd': {
                'offset': 70,
                'start': 0
            },
            'c': {
                'offset': 50,
                'start': 0
            }
        },
        'e': {
            'g': {
                'offset': 30,
                'start': 0
            },
            'h': {
                'offset': 20,
                'start': 0
            },
            'f': {
                'offset': 'CHANGED',
                'start': 0
            }
        },
        'a': {
            'offset': 100,
            'start': 0
        }
    }
}
```

You can revise some links regarding stuff which is used in the answer:

- [Recursion](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/recursion.html)
- [Visitor](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Visitor.html) pattern

Answer (score 0):

You could call a recursive function to change its value once condition is met:

```
dicti = {'files':
    {'a':{'offset':100, 'start': 0}, 
     'b':{
         'c':{'offset':50, 'start':0},
         'd':{'offset':70, 'start':0}  
         },
     'e':{
         'f':{'offset':80, 'start':0},
         'g':{'offset':30, 'start':0},  
         'h':{'offset':20, 'start':0}   
         } 
    }
}


def dictLoop(dt):
    for k, v in dt.items():
        if isinstance(v, int):
            if k == 'offset' and v > 50:
                dt[k] = 0
        else: dictLoop(v)
    return dt

print dictLoop(dicti)
```